# Proxmox server with just one public IP

Tags: openvz, proxmox

Is it possible to host a proxmox server with openvz containers NATed to the public IP which hosts the Proxmox server ?
I have gone through the proxmox feature list but I am somehow puzzled by the terminology used there.

So my plan would be to have one public IP for the server itself and NAT different services to the OpenVZ containers that would all have private IPs.
If this scenario is possible, who does the routing and NATing ? Proxmox or you need to configure this in the underlying operation system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use proxmox to host services on containers. You can forward ports using shorewall. There are several guides on how to forward ports using shorewall and proxmox.

Comment: So I understand that Proxmox doesn't provide any kind of routing or forwarding utilities ?

Comment: Not really, but in combination with iptables (shorewall) you can achieve what you want.